# How to authenticate user with company account on Actions on Google?

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I'm building a 3rd server to authenticate users with company accounts on google action. I use account linking with OAuth, Linking type: Implicit. I used ngrok.io to build.

**auth.js:**

```
const jwtHelper = require("../helpers/jwt.helper");

const accessTokenSecret = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET || "xxx";

let auth = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userFakeData = {
      email: req.body.email,
    };

    const accessToken = await jwtHelper.generateToken(userFakeData, accessTokenSecret);

   return res.status(200).json({"token_type": "Bearer", accessToke);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Form Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <form action="login" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jwt.helper.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

let generateToken = (user, secretSignature, tokenLife) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userData = {
      email: user.email,
    }
    jwt.sign(
      {data: userData},
      secretSignature,
      {
        algorithm: "HS256",
        expiresIn: tokenLife,
      },
      (error, token) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
        resolve(token);
    });
  });
}

let verifyToken = (token, secretKey) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (error, decoded) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      resolve(decoded);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  generateToken: generateToken,
  verifyToken: verifyToken,
};
```

middelware **auth.js**:

```
const jwtHelper = require('../helpers/jwt.helper');

const accessTokenSecret = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET || "xxx";

let isAuth = async(req, res, next) =>{
  const tokenFromCLient = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers["access-token"];
  if ( tokenFromCLient) {
    //thuc hien giai ma xem co hop len khong
    try{
      const decode = await jwtHelper.verifyToken(tokenFromCLient, accessTokenSecret);
      req.jwtDecoded = decode;
      next();
    }
    catch (error) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: Unauthorized})
    }
  }
  else {
    return res.status(403).send({message: 'No token provided'})
  }
}

module.exports = {
  isAuth: isAuth
}
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const AuthMiddleWare = require("../middleware/auth");
const AuthController = require("../controllers/AuthController");

let initAPIs = (app) => {
  router.post("/auth", AuthController.login);

  router.use(AuthMiddleWare.isAuth);
 return app.use("/", router);

}

module.exports = initAPIs;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const initAPIs = require("./routes/router");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/login.html'));
});
initAPIs(app);

app.listen(2310, () => {
  console.log("server is working in localhost:2310")
})
```

My account linking setup[image]

My Credentials Google Cloud :
[image]

This is what happened when I "talk to fun app"
[image]
After submit form :
[image]
Click link : 
[image]
Click link:
[image]
Nothing happened in Google Console
[image]

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - what is or isn't happening? If you can update your (otherwise very complete) question with any errors, logs, or examples of what is happening when you try, we will have a better chance of being able to help. It also looks ilke you've just shown the Auth Server portion, but it may be helpful to also see the portion of your fulfillment code where you're initiating the account linking.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner, I have updated my question. Please help me where I am wrong !